# Complement of a simple graph with one vertex/node?

Tags: graph-theory

For a simple graph of 1 node/vertex with no edges (null graph), what would the complement of this graph be?
Would it be a loop with itself or a null graph with one vertex? Or neither?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we keep the "simple" property of a graph under complementation. Hence, the complement of the simple graph, $G$, consisting of one vertex would be $G$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the same graph, since a simple graph cant have loops, and a complement graph has the same vertices as the original.